# Android: How to write multiple selectors in a single xml file

Tags: android, selector, imagebutton

In my application,I have 4 `ImageButtons` and each ImageButton have different source image based on their states.So maintaining 4 separate xml files for each of the button.

Is there any way to write all the selectors in a single xml file ?

Comment: where is the problem in having 3 extra files?

Comment: Multiple files can get very unwieldy very quickly.  It'd be nice to be able to organize these in a hierarchical way rather than having to rely on long filenames (and hope they are maintained correctly!).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not it's not possible:

The documentation says:
A StateListDrawable is a drawable object defined in XML that uses a several different images to represent the same graphic, depending on the state of the object.

note here: **same graphic**

src: [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: Oh fine.I thought there will be other way/hack to make it possible.